# When return type change from Stream<T> to Flux<T> what would be the respective change related implementation to act as reactive

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to *reactive programming*. I made changes in **DomainRepository** as following way :

**Changes in new updated Repository**:

- extends interface **ReactiveMongoRepository** from
  **MongoRepository**
- Method return type **Flux< DomainResponse >** from
  **Stream< DomainResponse >**

  ```
  public interface DomainRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<DomainResponse, UUID> {

      Flux<DomainResponse> findByRequestId(UUID requestId); 

  }
  ```

How can I made changes in following method so that it can work in the  same way as it was working with **MongoRepository** interface.

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var repository: DomainRepository

private fun fetchValidResponses(request: ModelRequest): Sequence<DomainResponse> {
    return repository.findByRequestId(request.requestId)
        .asSequence()
       
        .filter { it.product.intersect(request.product).isNotEmpty() }
      
        .filter { it.errors == null || it.errors!!.isEmpty() }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reactive implementation in Java would be like this:

```java
private Flux<DomainResponse> fetchValidResponses(ModelRequest request) {
    return repository.findByRequestId(request.getRequestId())
              .filter(response -> { /* filtering */})
}
```